# What is your favorite convention for organizing a ASP.NET project?

Tags: .net, asp.net, naming-conventions, conventions

My team is starting a brand new ASP.NET solution which will probably become large.   Inspired by ASP.NET MVC, we currently express all data access objects in a model project.   We, however, do not have good conventions for organizing ASP.NET ascx's and aspx's.

We have already reviewed DotNetNuke and want to avoid the complexity of driving the whole application through a single default.aspx .

What is the best way to organize a non-MVC ASP.NET solution?  Your tips, links, and advice are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we organize our solution. Following would be the folders:

1. **Stylesheet** (under this **Themes** for various JQuery UI themes to be present)
2. **Javascript** (under this two folders **Custom** page specific JS and **Library**--Jquery, Jquery-UI etc)
3. **DataFiles** (all our http handlers .ashx go here. We use AJAX a lot so all our data passing is through HTTP handlers)
4. **Components** (all our user controls go here)
5. **Attachments** (all the attachments made goes here)
6. **Role based folders** like Admin, Employees, Public (so that we can set the authentication and authorization in web.config and be done with it)

Generally we keep role based aspx in their respective folders and other general aspx files outside at the root. To add to what we have created we have App_Code and App_Data but those two are ASP .net folders and we don't actually create them.

HTH